# Ionic 3 - Manually trigger blur event

Tags: javascript, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic3

I would like to know if there is anyway to manually trigger the blur event on a `ion-input` element?

The best would be with an ionic-native method, but any javascript-based trick will do.

My config:

```
Ionic:

   ionic (Ionic CLI)  : 4.0.1 (/Users/rguerin/.nvm/versions/node/v6.10.1/lib/node_modules/ionic)
   Ionic Framework    : ionic-angular 3.1.1
   @ionic/app-scripts : 1.3.7

System:

   NodeJS : v6.10.1 (/Users/rguerin/.nvm/versions/node/v6.10.1/bin/node)
   npm    : 3.10.10
   OS     : macOS High Sierra
```

My html file :

```
<div>    
   <ion-input (click)="openModal(fieldName)" [placeholder]="placeholder" #searchInput>
   </ion-input>
</div>
```

My component file :

```
export class MyClass implements OnInit {

   @ViewChild('searchInput') searchInput: any;

   foo(): void {
      this.searchInput.blur();
   }
}
```

The `this.searchInput.blur()` triggers the following error :

> TypeError: this.searchInput.setBlur is not a function. (In
>   'this.searchInput.setBlur()', 'this.searchInput.setBlur' is undefined)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most straightforward way to programmatically blur an element is to first grab the element via `@ViewChild` then call `.setBlur()` on that element.  Something like:

```
export class HomePage {
  @ViewChild('myInput') myInput;

  onBlurClicked() {
    this.myInput.setBlur();
  }
}
```

And in your template, do something like `<ion-input #myInput></ion-input>` for your input, and make a button with a click event callback to `onBlurClicked`.  I put a working stackblitz example here:  https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-blank-3-9-2-owhgpf

edit: as this does not seem to be working with your version of ionic, you can try blurring the native element directly, e.g.:

```
export class HomePage {
  @ViewChild('myInput', { read: ElementRef }) myInput: ElementRef;

  onBlurClicked() {
    // Call the vanilla js .blur() method on the native element.
    this.myInput.nativeElement.blur();
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I already tried this one and got the following error : "TypeError: this.searchInput.setBlur is not a function. (In 'this.searchInput.setBlur()', 'this.searchInput.setBlur' is undefined)". I added my code above for more details.

Comment: I think it might be a version issue, as you are using an older version of Ionic 3 (current is 3.9.2).  Another possibility, change the `@ViewChild` line to `@ViewChild('myInput', { read: ElementRef }) myInput: ElementRef;` then call `.blur()` on the native element:  `this.myInput.nativeElement.blur();`.  I've updated the answer and stackblitz to reflect this.